# Softmax and Sigmoid identity in TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I understand that the sigmoid function is identical to the softmax function with two categories (`K=5`). Yet I don't understand why TensorFlow 2 gives me different results here, where I compare a bottom-up calculation of cross-entropy with the cross-entropy function of Tensorflow:

```py
print('SIGMOID')

a = tf.convert_to_tensor([1, 1], dtype='float32')
b = tf.convert_to_tensor([0.6, 0.4])

print(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=a, logits=b))
print(-tf.math.log(tf.math.sigmoid(b))) 

# both yield: [0.43748793 0.5130153]

print('SOFTMAX')

a = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1, 0],[1, 0]], dtype='float32') # one-hot
b = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0.6, 0.4],[0.4, 0.6]])

print(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=a, logits=b)) 
print(-tf.math.log(tf.nn.softmax(tf.convert_to_tensor([0.6,0.4]))))

# both yield [0.59813887 0.79813886]
```

As far as I understand it, they should result in the same results. Mathematically, I came as far as the following (cross-entropy again):

[image]

These results also come out of the above functions but are obviously not the same. Can anybody resolve this inconsistency?

(I'm aware of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233658/softmax-vs-sigmoid-function-in-logistic-classifier) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87248/is-binary-logistic-regression-a-special-case-of-multinomial-logistic-regression#comment609940_87270) which are quite questions.)

Comment: Your formulas for sigmoid and softmax arent correct. 
Sigmoid works on single value input (binary classification).
Softmax works on multi input (multiclass classification).
If you provide multiple inputs to sigmoid operator in tensorflow it will just calculate sigmoid of each element.

check http://dataaspirant.com/2017/03/07/difference-between-softmax-function-and-sigmoid-function/

Comment: I see that they are not the same but in what way are they incorrect each on its own? I wonder how for two classes they become identical.